# IONIC ion-toggle windows phone 8.1 & 10

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework, ion-toggle

Developing with Ionic has been a fun ride!
Now that windows phone 8.1 is officially supported I wanted to give it a try.
So far so good, the only problem I had was when clicking a toggle it will act as if it was pressed twice.
If the toggle is OFF and is clicked it will go to ON and then immediately to OFF, but the action behind the toggle is fired only once. Meaning this is a sort of animation issue or something wrong with the CSS?
After doing some research and disabling the native java scrolling option, it works fine on a Windows phone 8.1 device.
But the problem persists on a Windows phone 10 device :( while the problem was solved on the 8.1 device.

Does anyone know more about this "double click" issue with toggles on Windows phone 8.1 & 10?
Probably you guy's know a better work @ to this issue.
Thank you guys in advance for your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

> These links below may be useful

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/windows-phone-ionic-cordova-select-element-issue/
http://devinitely.azurewebsites.net/2015/04/10/developing-ionic-app-for-windows-phone-8-1/

> This should solve your problem **data-tap-disabled**

```
<button data-tap-disabled="true" />
```